# Find words not containing a slash

Tags: regex

I have links like below:
`https://www.aparat.com/v/xxx` and
`https://www.aparat.com/v/xxx/yyy`

I want to find the links not having slash after `/v/`. So the first link is ok and the second one is not.

I have tried lots and lots of regex but all of them matched the links until the first slash like: **https://www.aparat.com/v/xxx/** yyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is that you have to check that there are no slash characters **up until the end of the string** (marked by `$` in regex):

```
\/v\/[^\/]*$
```

[image]
Where:

- `\/v\/` - The `/v/` part
- `[^\/]*` - Any character that is not a slash `/`. Since the next pattern is already `$`, then this must span up to the end of the string.
- `$` - End of string

---

**Update**

On top of the rules above, we could allow an additional slash if it isn't followed by any characters by simply appending the optional `/?` at the end:

```
\/v\/[^\/]*\/?$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Niel. It worked for me and I accept this answer but I faced another issue. I need to accept the links having only one slash but not the links having a slash and other characters after it. So we accpet ```https://www.aparat.com/v/xxx/``` but not ```https://www.aparat.com/v/xxx/yyy```

Comment: @MinaSoleimanzadeh I updated my answer, just append the optional `\/?` in the end of the string before the `$`. Please check if it works.